# Human error analysis in general aviation

Tags: flight-controls, general-aviation, instrument-flight-rules, emergency-procedures, human-factors

can anybody help me with understanding more about the human factors analysis in general aviation Controlled flight into terrain. I am researching on the topic and I would really appreciate any help in getting further insights.

Edit 1:
As a part of my research on "Designing a sensory warning system to reduce General Aviation Controlled Flight into Terrain". I need to understand the following factors for a pilot during the process of flying:

- Mental workload
- Decision making
- Skilled performance
- Human-computer interaction
- Human reliability
- Work stress and training

I need to understand the above points with a behavioral and cognitive ergonomics point of view.

Comment: [HERE](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_61-134_Editorial_Update.pdf) is an FAA advisory circular regarding general aviation Controlled Flight Into Terrain. Is this the type of information you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this.  I am looking forward to understanding the pilot's first hand perspective in such situations. I am designing a sensory warning system that would act as a fail-safe measure in case of interpretation errors of warning signs or wrong actions. Would really appreciate for any leads. Thanks again.

Comment: @SoumyajitMaiti Welcome to Aviation.SE! Your question is a bit vague at the moment. Can you please [edit](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/101268/edit) it to include all details from your comment and anything else that may help to provide a more specific answer?

Comment: @Bianfable I can expalin in detail in case you would like to get in touch. I am looking forward to get some qualitative insights rather than quantitative insights, that would help me in better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a helpful starting point for your research: ([Source for the full document](https://commons.erau.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2314&context=publication)):

[image]

Here is the Abstract from the document referenced above:

[image]

Comment: Can you summarize or quote the key points from this document? Otherwise this is essentially a link only answer...

Comment: @Bianfable One thing I would like to point here is that I want to understand qualitatively rather than a quantitative approach because when it comes to designing a solution, I need to look at the nuances in the processes.